# Обработка исключений с помощью throw c#

Tags: c#

Проблема в том что необходимо обработать исключения с помощью выражения `throw`, я только обучаюсь и нужно выполнить задание с юнит тестами. Задание требует реализовать `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` c переменными `day` & `month`, а также `ArgumentNullException` c перeменной `username`

```cs
public static string GenerateUserCode(int day, int month, string username)
{
    if (day < 1 && day > 31)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(day));
    }
    else if (month < 1 && month > 12)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(month));
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));
    }
    else if (username is string)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(username));
    }
    else
    {
        return $"{username}-{day}{month}";
    }
}
```

Проблема в `return` он возвращает мне `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, но юнит тест не проходит, я посмотрел сам юнит тест он проверяет переменную username на значения `null`, пустая строка и строка со значением.

Сначала я написал метод в `ArgumentNullException` `string.IsNullorEmpty`; без конструкции `else-if` `ArgumentOutOfRange`; тесты частично проходили, а те которые не проходили, параметром возвращали `null` хотя требовалось ввести строку со значением, я решил добавить блок `else-if` с `ArgumentOutOfRange` теперь тест проходил но ссылался на `return` и выдавал в окне обозревателя сообщение `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values`

может я неправильно написал `return`? Pls Help

Comment: `username is string` - это же всегда true

Comment: @tym32167, если не брать во внимания остальные проверки, то `username is string` может быть false, если `username==null`

Comment: @Grundy но вроде он будет стрингом со значением null, нет? Мы же вроде не может засунуть любой налл в любой тип данных, это будет нал конкретного типа данных.

Comment: @Andrew, будет, но проверка `is` при участии в ней `null` возвращает `false`, исключение только `is var`, на сколько помню - она всегда `true` возвращает

Comment: @Andrew, собственно вот [_The is expression is true if expr isn't null_](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern)

Comment: ок, спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам столько `else`? И `return` здесь не при чем. Вы можете вообще все свои проверки убрать, и у вас не выскочит исключения совсем. Проблема именно в проверках `day` и `month`.

Проверка типа `day < 1 && day > 31` будет всегда `false`, потому что значение одной и той же переменной не может быть меньше 1 и одновременно больше 31. Логично? Надо `||`.

Если аргумент типа `string` проверить на `is string`, то будет `true` если не `null`, то есть это исключение `IndexOutOfRange` будет выброшено в любом случае. Я бы убрал эту проверку, потому что предыдущая гарантирует, что дальнейшее выполнение кода будет только в том случае, если строка не пустая. И я бы проверял на `null` и длину строки отдельно.

```cs
public static string GenerateUserCode(int day, int month, string username)
{
    if (day < 1 || day > 31)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(day));
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(month));
    if (username is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));
    if (username.Trim().Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("User name was blank", nameof(username));

    return $"{username}-{day}{month}";
}
```